# using jar in codegenerator with xtext

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, dsl, xtext

in my Xtext programm I have the following Problem:

I use Codegeneration (doGenerate method) for writing an interpreter. This interpreter needs the import of a jar.

(Probably important to mention here is that ) importing that Jar in a testprogramm without xtext showed that to use the jar not only adding it to configure build path -> classpath but also to run configurations -> classpath was necessary.
With Xtext the import to build path is no problem but since the runtime environment is used for the editor of my DSL I dont know how to deal with runtime in terms of that jar.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: you should add the jar using eclipse means (build.properties + Runtime/Classpath in Manifest)

Comment: maybe even in a separate bundle exporting it.

Comment: Thank you, runtime/classpath in Manifest solved he problem!